# How to import pipe delimited text file data to SQLServer table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have database table represented as text file in the following pattern:

```
0|ALGERIA|0| haggle. carefully f|
1|ARGENTINA|1|al foxes promise|
2|BRAZIL|1|y alongside of the pendal |
3|CANADA|1|eas hang ironic, silent packages. |
```

I need to import this data to a SQL Server 2008 database table. I have created the table with the types matching the schema.

How to import this data to the table?

EDIT: Solved by following the answer selected. 
Note to anyone stumbling upon this in  future: The datatype needs to be converted. 
Refer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/94399ff2-616c-44d5-972d-ca8623c8014e

Comment: +1 for edit to help future readers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `Import Data` feature by right mouse clicking the database, and then clicking Tasks then `Import Data`. This will give you a wizard which you can specify the delimiters etc. for your file and preview the output before you've inserted any data.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a large amount of data you can use bcp to bulk import from file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

> The bcp utility bulk copies data
>   between an instance of Microsoft SQL
>   Server and a data file in a
>   user-specified format. The bcp utility
>   can be used to import large numbers of
>   new rows into SQL Server tables... 
>   Except when used with the
>   queryout option, the utility requires
>   no knowledge of Transact-SQL. To
>   import data into a table, you must
>   either use a format file created for
>   that table or understand the structure
>   of the table and the types of data
>   that are valid for its columns.