# Import large delimited .txt file in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Every morning one of my clients send me a .txt file with ' **;** ' as separator, and this is how the file is currently being imported in a temp table using SSIS:

```
mario.mascarenhas;MARIO LUIZ MASCARENHAS;2017-03-21 13:18:22;PDV;94d33a66dbaaff15a01d8139c7acd7c6;;;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;\N
evilanio.asevedo;EVILANIO ASEVEDO;2017-03-21 13:26:10;PDV;30a1bd072ac5f158f99445bb0975e423;;;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;\N
marcelo.tarso;MARCELO TARSO;2017-03-21 13:47:09;PDV;ef6b5e971242ec345552cdb724968f8a;;;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;\N
tiago.rodrigues;TIAGO ALVES RODRIGUES;2017-03-21 13:49:04;PDV;d782d4b30c0d302fe815b2cb48de4d03;;;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;\N
roberto.freire;ROBERTO CUSTODIO;2017-03-21 13:54:53;PDV;78794a18187f068d612e6b6370a60781;;;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;\N
eduardo.lima;EDUARDO MORO LIMA;2017-03-21 13:55:24;PDV;83e1c2696faa83d54881b13c70a07924;;;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;\N
```

Each file constains at least 23,000 rows just like that. 
I already made a table with the correct number of columns to receive this data. So what I want is to "explode" (just like in PHP) the row using ' **;** ' as the column separator and loop the insert in my table named `dbo.showHistoricalLogging`.

I've been searching for a solution here in Stack but nothing specific having this volume of data in consideration and looping an insert.

Any idea? I'm running SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I may be missing something, but in an SSIS flat file connection manager you can set the column delimiter to `;` and simply map the columns to your table and import.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import pipe delimited text file data to SQLServer table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967006/how-to-import-pipe-delimited-text-file-data-to-sqlserver-table)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion,

convert the text file into a csv file, then refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server) from StackOverFlow to use the Bulk package. I have used this before while I was in University of Arizona for one of my programming assignments in my Database Designs class. Any clarifications and/or question, leave in a comment and will do my best.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
BULK INSERT [TableName] FROM 'C:\MyFile.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', ROWTERMINATOR = '\\N');
```

consult the Microsoft [Bulk Insert documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) if you need other parameters. Alternatively SSIS makes this super easy as well - many ways you could do this honestly.

Comment: bulk loading is only accepted here where I work if your user is an admin, not in my case, that's why i am looking for some other way

Comment: Are you able to use bulk inserts via SSIS?