# Insert text file data into SQL Server database table of specific column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have attached my code in which I tried to read a `.txt` file with many records.

The same text file data I need to insert into the SQL Server database table in specific columns. Here is the code I wrote by taking reference from some where.

```
protected void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload(x);
}

private void FileUpload(List<string> x)
{       
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    string fileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\SBS", FileUpload1.FileName);        

    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            List<string> x;

            for (int i = 0; i <= x.Count - 9; i += 9)
            {
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SBSFile (SBSBranchCode, BranchName, FinYear, BrChallanNo, TransDate, MajorHead, ReceiptPayment, Amount, PlanNonPlan) " +
                           string.Format("Values('{0}', '{1}',  '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}')", x[i], x[i + 1], x[i + 2], x[i + 3], x[i + 4], x[i + 5], x[i + 6], x[i + 7], x[i + 8], x[i + 9]), con);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
         }
     }
 }
```

example of my file :

> 1 |abc| |bcd| |101|

here `|` denoted separator of column and yes every line should be inserted in the table where in specific column is available

Can anyone help me to insert file data into the SQL Server table?

Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: You need to describe what the issue is before anyone can offer a suggestion to solve it. Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error? Is data being inserted into incorrect columns?

Comment: I am getting error in function call i am unable to call that function i made and i want to confirm that the code i have wrote will be sufficient to perform a job or not

Comment: how is your file? every line in file must be insert in a column in dataBase?

Comment: example of my file : 1 |abc| |bcd| |101|       here "|" denoted separator of column and yes every line should be inserted in the table where in specific column is available

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: What is the exception? Your catch block is empty so it's not going to surface anything useful to you. add a `throw` in there so you can see what's going wrong.

Comment: if you have any alternative codes to perform the task. i wld be grateful but just before to put the question i removed the catch and finally block code my issue is not the one u said thank u dear

Comment: You still haven't told us what the issue is - please [edit] your question to clarify that. My bet would be that using parameters will fix the problem, as well as protecting you from SQL injection attacks. Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` are both `IDisposable` so should be in `using` blocks.

Comment: @Bhawani Please don't add significantly important information in comments. When this happens, you should [edit] the question instead. I have done this for you - please ensure my edit reflects what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a program at all... I'd use the "Import" feature in SQL server to import a pipe-delimited file. For example [How to import pipe delimited text file data to SQLServer table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967006/how-to-import-pipe-delimited-text-file-data-to-sqlserver-table)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of working code that will read data from a Text file, where that data is delimited by `|`. Multiple insert statements will be executed within a single transaction, in case of failure using an All Or Nothing principle.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestInsertDataFromFile()
{
    String fileName = @"D:\SampleData.txt";
    String connectionString = @"Server=MyTestDBServer; Database=TestingDatabase; Trusted_Connection=True;";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            String insertCommand = @"INSERT INTO SBSFile (SBSBranchCode, BranchName, FinYear, BrChallanNo, TransDate, MajorHead, ReceiptPayment, Amount, PlanNonPlan) ";
            insertCommand += @"VALUES (@sbsBranchCode, @branchName, @finYear, @brChallanNo, @transDate, @majorHead, @receiptPayment, @amount, @planNonPlan)";

            String[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

            using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = insertCommand;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                foreach (String dataLine in fileContent)
                {
                    String[] columns = dataLine.Split('|');
                    command.Parameters.Clear();

                    command.Parameters.Add("sbsBranchCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = columns[0];
                    command.Parameters.Add("branchName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = columns[1];
                    command.Parameters.Add("finYear", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = columns[2];
                    command.Parameters.Add("brChallanNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = columns[3];
                    command.Parameters.Add("transDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = columns[4];
                    command.Parameters.Add("majorHead", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = columns[5];
                    command.Parameters.Add("receiptPayment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = columns[6];
                    command.Parameters.Add("amount", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = columns[7];
                    command.Parameters.Add("planNonPlan", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = columns[8];

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Important things to note**

1. NEVER have an empty `catch {}` handler as you will never know if there are problems.
2. When talking to the database using externally specified values, ALWAYS use parameters to prevent SQL Injection attacks.
3. Make use of Transactions if you are doing multiple inserts from a single source. It will make recovery possible without having to unpick the data manually.
4. Where possible (when classes implement *IDisposable*) use a `using(...)` block to ensure resources are released and not blocking/locking.

Comment: @Richardissimo The OP commented *yes every line should be inserted in the table where in specific column is available* Made me think that every field should be in its own column with one row per line

Comment: Apologies.. that's significant information which should have been edited and added to the question rather than being in a comment. I will edit it.

Answer (score -1):

use this code:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        string fileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\SBS", FileUpload1.FileName);

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    var columns = line.Split('|');
                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SBSFile (SBSBranchCode, BranchName, FinYear, BrChallanNo, TransDate, MajorHead, ReceiptPayment, Amount, PlanNonPlan) " +
                               $"Values('{columns[0]}', '{columns[1]}','{columns[2]}','{columns[3]}','{columns[4]}','{columns[5]}','{columns[6]}','{columns[7]}','{columns[8]}''{columns[9]}')");
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: This answer suffers the same SQLInjection, resource leaking and exception suppressing issues of the original code which have been highlighted in the comments. It includes an unused variable.